# Dynamic SendTo annotation

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I have Java code as following to receive messages form a queue, process it and write processed message to another queue.

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = "rawFusion")
    @SendTo("Fusion")
    public String receiverFusion(Object _message) {
        String message = getMessage(_message);
        return messageParser.parse(message);
    }
```

Here i always get messages from "rawFusion" queue and write it into "Fusion" queue.

The thing I want to do is, writing messages different queues depending on some conditions. So i would like decide  `@SendTo` parameter (or maybe without using `@SendTo`) after i receive message from the "RawFusion" queue.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the sender sets the `replyTo` message property (either a queue name or `exchange/routkingKey`), the container will use that. The `@SendTo` is only used if there's not `replyTo` in the message.

If you can't change the sender, when using @RabbitListener, the `@SendTo` can contain a SpEL expression but it doesn't have any context from the request, which I suspect you would need to intelligently route the reply.

You could store something in a ThreadLocal and use

```
@SendTo("#{someBean.someMethod()}")
```

to retrieve it.

I will open a JIRA issue to see if we can come up with a mechanism to provide some context (e.g. input arguments) to the evaluation.

**EDIT**

[Starting with version 1.6, the @SendTo can be a SpEL expression that is evaluated at runtime against the request and reply](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven-reply). `@SendTo("!{'some.reply.queue.with.' + result.queueName}")`

Comment: [Starting with version 1.6, the @SendTo can be a SpEL expression that is evaluated at runtime against the request and reply](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven-reply). `@SendTo("!{'some.reply.queue.with.' + result.queueName}")`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot make any change on sender's message and it seems SpEL expression does not solve my problem in this case. But I found a workaround. I am not sure if its a good practice but it solves my problem for now.

I used `@SendTo("exchange/")` i didnt use any routing key.
In my message i set a header value like "destination=testQueue" and i created an headers exchange which route my message depending on destination value.

Thanks for your answer and i hope we can have a mechanism that we can determine `@SendTo` value after we receive the Message.