# How to stop replyTo so that @SendTo works

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have Java code similar to this in a class called "MyService" to receive messages, process the object passed and return a response, with the intention to have the returned response using the configured exchange and routing key, as specified using the @SendTo annotation:

```
@RabbitListener(containerFactory = "myContainerFactory", queues = RabbitConfig.MY_QUEUE_NAME)
@SendTo("#{T(com.acme.config.RabbitOutboundConfig).OUTBOUND_EXCHANGE_NAME + '/' + myService.getRoutingKey()}")
public OrderResponse handlePaidOrder(Order order) {
    // do processing on the input Order object here...
    OrderResponse orderResponse = new OrderResponse();
    // fill up response object here
    return orderResponse;
}

public String getRoutingKey() {
    String routingKey;
    // .. custom logic to build a routing key
    return routingKey;
}
```

This makes sense and works fine.  The problem I am having is I can't figure out how to stop the "reply_to" property from coming in the message.  I know if my sender configures a RabbitTemplate by calling setReplyAddress, that will result in a reply_to property and a correlation_id in the message.

However, if I simply do not call setReplyAddress, I still get a reply_to property, one that looks like this:

reply_to:  amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkAAxyYWJiaXRAd3NK and so forth

and with that reply_to in the message, @SendTo has no effect.  The Spring AMQP docs and this post:  [Dynamic SendTo annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583708) state:

*The @SendTo is only used if there's no replyTo in the message.*

Furthermore, when I don't call setReplyAddress on the RabbitTemplate, I don't get a correlation-id either.  I pretty sure I am going to need that.  So, my question is, how do I get my sender to generate a correlation-id but to not generate a reply-to so that my receiver can use the @SendTo annotation?

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correlationId is for the sender; it's not needed with direct reply-to since the channel is reserved; you could add a `MessagePostProcessor` on the sending side to add a correlationId.

The `@SendTo` is a fallback in case there is no reply_to header.

If you want to change that behavior you can add an `afterReceivePostProcessor` to the listener container to remove the `replyTo` property on the `MessageProperties`.

```
container.setAfterReceivePostProcessor(m -> {
        m.getMessageProperties().setReplyTo(null);
        return m;
}
```

Bear in mind, though, that if the sender set a replyTo, he is likely expecting a reply, so sending the reply someplace else is going to disappoint him and likely will cause some delay there until the reply times out.

If you mean you want to send an initial reply someplace else that does some more work and then finally replies to the originator, then you should save off the replyTo in another header, and reinstate it (or use an expression that references the saved-off header).

Comment: Bear in mind, though, that if the sender set a replyTo, he is likely expecting a reply, so sending the reply someplace else is going to disappoint him and likely will cause some delay there until the reply times out.

Comment: Great answer, Gary.  That helped a lot.